# Display a css class based on a given db record

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii but I'm trying to understand a good logic to implement this, so even if your not a Yii proficient I could use a help.

We have those *event types* with names that may containing special characters like:

"Amça"

"Áli Çulo"

etc...

I cannot simple grab those names and call statically the model on view to display those, because I will get an invalid css class.

The model:

```
/**
* @desc Get Event Type Name normalized. 
* @param int $id
* @return object 
*/
 public function getEventTypeName($id) {
  return normalizer_normalize(self::model()->findByPk($id)->name);
 }
```

The view:

```
<p class="event-resume-<?= function_exists('normalizer_normalize') ? EventType::getEventTypeName($data->event->type) : '';?>"></p>
```

I've tried to user normalizer_normalize but, it doesn't work with "Áli Çulo" due to the space between the words.

**The logic issue:**

We can create a method that says:

*If the id is 1 then return a constant string named "nameoftype1"

If the id is 2 then return a constant string named "nameoftype2"*

But this is not a good approach because if we later have another database were other id's, correspond to other types, we need to change this method again.

**What would be a better approach here ?**

Should I provide more information? Please advice.

Comment: Do you want to load a CSS file named after an event, ie. `ali_culo.css` ?

Comment: @Örs No. I wish to only return a string in order to place it as a class name. Then, on the css, we may have: `.event-resume-ali-culo { //csshere }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a hash value of the event type and use that instead:

```
<p class="event-resume-<?= md5( $data->event->type ) ?>"></p>
```

This might cause the .css file to be less readable, but you can use comments to deal with that.

Comment: Well, true that I will get a strange name on both the html code and the css class declaration. But truth being told, according to this that we are trying to implement we should always change the CSS if a new event arrives... do you believe this is a nice approach, or another completely different should apply ?

Comment: If you want nice names you have to use a mapping structure. If you are using a database, just add another field (`CssClassName`) to the `EventType` table. If not, just create a php array mapping the event type to the css class name. In any case, you should not map ids to class names as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I will use md5. :)